# Flutter. Intercepting events from Parents

Tags: flutter, widget, touch

1. I have parent with horizontal touch area (similar to `Drawer`), it's located in `Stack` and intercept all the events. In some cases I might have child with same scrolling direction, let's say `Slider`. Obviously it will absorbs all the events in that area.

Question. Is there a way to wrap child inside some `Widget`, which will prevent parent intercepting touch request, and consume it within child. Something opposite to the `AbsorbPointer`?

Comment: Could you possibly be looking for [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)?

Comment: @Sven It's working almost the same way. It will intercept on all *childs* under the tree.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I misunderstood your question. Is the current behavior that the parent (the one similar to `Drawer`) absorbs all the events that should go to the child (in your example `Slider`)?

Comment: @Sven yes, it's on top of everything.